# Mass texting - iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, sms

This is in regard to Objective-C in an iPhone app...

I have figured out how to get a list of all contacts on my iPhone, but is it possible to send out a mass text? I know I can make a message composer which has an array of recipients, but that will end up sending the text as a group text, not as an individual text to each person.

Also, is there a way to send a text message in iOS without using a message composer?

Comment: iOS won't let you send sms (or email or make phone calls) from your app w/o the user's consent.

Comment: and what about doing it without group texting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely no, at least not without jailbreaking.  This is the sort of thing that Apple wouldn't allow developers access to just to prevent any possible abuse by the same (especially when it might cost a user a small chunk of change if a mass-text got sent out).

Answer (score 0):

MFMessageComposeViewController is your best bet. You'll be able to specify an array of phone numbers to send SMS to. As for group messaging, I would assume it would default to the users settings. (This is an option in Settings.app) It's simple enough to test but the documentation doesn't mention it.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009668